# Select a RadGrid Row (Client-side) inside RadWindows

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadGrid inside of RadWindow.
I need to select a Radgrid row in clientside.
How can I do that?

I´m trying to get the radgrid like that:

```
var masterTable = $find("<%=radgridID.ClientID%>").get_masterTableView();
```

but always getting null...

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it...
Code :

```
var oManager = GetRadWindowManager();  
var oWnd = oManager.GetWindowByName("RadWindow1");     
var grid = oWnd.GetContentFrame().contentWindow.$find('RadGrid1') //Get reference to RadGrid 
var masterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();  
masterTable.selectItem(3);  //Select 4th row
```

Answer (score 4):

Is your Javascript inside a RadCodeBlock:

```
<telerik:HeadTag runat="server" ID="Headtag2"></telerik:HeadTag>
    <!-- custom head section -->
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            function RowSelected(sender, args)
            {
                document.getElementById("<%= Label1.ClientID %>").innerHTML =
                 "<b>CustomerID: </b>" + args.getDataKeyValue("CustomerID") +
                 "<br />" +
                 "<b>CompanyName: </b>" + args.getDataKeyValue("CompanyName");
            }

            function GetFirstDataItemKeyValues()
            {
             var firstDataItem = $find("<%= RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ClientID %>").get_dataItems()[0];
             var keyValues =
                    'CustomerID: "' + firstDataItem.getDataKeyValue("CustomerID") + '"' +
                 ' \r\n' +
                 'CompanyName: "' + firstDataItem.getDataKeyValue("CompanyName") + '"';
             alert(keyValues);
            }
            -->
        </script>
        </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
    <!-- end of custom head section -->
</head>
```

Here is the [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/keys/defaultcs.aspx) to the sample.  I made the same error of just including the javascript function but without the code block tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
var grid = $find("<%=grdList.ClientID %>");
var firstDataItem = grid.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[grid._selectedIndexes[0]];
var keyValues = firstDataItem.getDataKeyValue("id_estadoreq");
alert(keyValues);
```

Try this!